# Magento 2 get country Id when on change in estimate shipping on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, jquery

Due to some custom requirement on cart page, I need country id when someone change it using jquery.

[image]

I have tried with below jquery script but its not working.

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $('select[name="country_id"]').on("click",function(){
        alert('hi');
        var countyId=$(this).filter(":selected").val();
        alert(countyId);
    });
      
  });
});
</script>
```

please share your idea on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using `quote` object in JS. See code below. Might have to change a bit according to your requirements.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, Element, quoteData) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
getCountryId: function () {         
            if(quoteData.shippingAddress() !== null && quoteData.shippingAddress() !== undefined ){
                //do something
                //get country id with quoteData.shippingAddress().countryId
            }
 });
});
```

Sorry, if there are some syntax errors while copying and editing it, hope you get that. And also you can write this function in other ways, but main thing was using `quote`.